Why is the universe depicted as elliptical in all images?
Is there a physical equation that describes the ellipse of the Universe? It seems to me that this is not the case, as most of the motions within it are chaotic (with the exception of the many motions of galaxies in a single direction, which experts have observed).
The observable universe has a radius that is unrelated to an ellipse, as you say. This is correct.
Perhaps those who have created such images have not fully understood how the motions of point masses can be described?
Links to visual representations of scientific models of the universe.


I think that's a Mollweide projection.

This question is similar to: Why is the universe map shaped like an oval?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To be clear - the ellipse does not represent the shape of the universe, it is a projection of  how we see the universe, which is a 3D sphere (since we can see in all directions).  The 3D sphere could have been projected onto a rectangle (many maps of the world use a rectangular projection) but a different projection was used because it preserves areas.
